# Branch and pole structure for function

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

I  am trying to solve the integral
$$
\int^{\infty}_{0}dz\frac{ze^{-zt}}{\sqrt{z^2+g^2}}
$$
Using complex analysis and I am a bit unsure of the branch point structure of the function. Could someone tell me where the branch cut should be on the complex plane? P.s. don’t solve the integral for me, I want to do the rest of the steps after this.

Comment: Does the integral converge?

Comment: Good point, the integration range is meant to be [0,$\infty$)

Comment: Actually, I’m solving the integral which I got this from a different way as this doesn’t work but I’d  still like to know how one would structure the branches in this function as my books on complex analysis aren’t very clear

Comment: I studied the integral $f(t)=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-tz}}{z^2+1}dz$ three years ago. $f(t)$ is analytic in $\operatorname{Re} t>0$ and has the (single valued) analytic continuation to $\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty, 0]$. $f(t)$ has a branch point at $t=0$. I'd like to study whether my approach is applicable or not for your function.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified, t and g are arbitrary constants rather than variables, I was wondering where one would place branch cuts on the complex plane. The square root makes the function multi valued on the imaginary axis. Would one create a cut from 0 to i($\infty$)? I’m just a bit unsure